# FIleSystemWatcher IOException

Tags: c#, process, stack-trace, filesystemwatcher, windows-defender

I have a Windows Service that monitors a folder for new files and runs a process.  However, the service crashes every time I drop files into the monitored folder.  Here is the Exception I am receiving:

> Application: Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process
>   was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.IO.IOException Stack:    at System.IO._*Error.WinIOError(Int32,
>   System.String)    at System.IO.*_Error.WinIOError()    at
>   System.IO.File.Move(System.String, System.String)    at
>   Service.Service.Process(System.String, System.String)    at
>   Service.Service.OnChanged(System.Object,
>   System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)    at
>   System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.OnCreated(System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
>   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFileSystemEventArgs(Int32,
>   System.String)    at
>   System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32, UInt32,
>   System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)    at
>   System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32,
>   UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)

Everything was working fine and then all of the sudden, it crashes every time I use it.  I don't remember changing anything that would cause this.  Here is my code:

```
public Service()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadPath"]);

    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

public static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Process(e.Name, e.FullPath);
}

public static void Process(string fileName, string path)
{
    string newPath = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewPath"], fileName);

    Process process = new Process();

    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\Antimalware\mpcmdrun";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = " -scan -scantype 3 -file L:\\Test\\";

    process.Start();

    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();

    if (process.ExitCode == 0)
    {
        File.Move(path, cleanPath);
    }

    else
    {
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedPath"] + fileName + ".txt");
        tw.WriteLine(output);
        tw.Close();

        File.Delete(path);
    }
}
protected override void OnStop()
{

}
```

Comment: Does the account the service runs under still have rights to create documents in the target directory of the Move operation?

Comment: catch the exception in the Process method.  It's throwing in the File.Move.  See what the exception is, in order to figure out what to do about it.

Comment: surround the line throwing the exception with a try/catch-block and output information about the context. Maybe the file is still locked by your drag&drop operation. You should use the `using` keyword with TextWriter.

Comment: You should also dispose your Process object.

Comment: @Stuart.  Yes the account does have rights to the folder.

Comment: @Cheeso.  I added a try catch and it looks like it is failing before the file is completely moved to the server.  I think yas4891 is right that the file is still locked.  What can I do to get around this?

Comment: Here is the catch: System.InvalidOperationException: No process is associated with this object.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_HasExited()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_ExitCode()
   at Service.Service.OnChanged(Object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)

Comment: It looks like adding a sleep worked.  I don't like it but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added Thread.Sleep(5000) before the creation of the process.  This works well but it does at 5 seconds to the scanning of each file.  And, as people have stated people, it feels kind of hackish.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the process still has a lock on the file in some cases. Just wondering, why aren't you calling:

```
process.Close(); // Frees all the resources that are associated with this component
```

after WaitForExit().

Comment: I was lazy.  I will add that now.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that another process, say another instance of the scanner you're manually starting, still holds a lock to the file at the moment you try to move it?

You should use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see which processes are accessing the file.

Anyway, you don't scan the new file, you always scan the whole folder L:\Test. Is that your intention?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do following checks just after making sure the process existed with 0, like this,

```
if (process.ExitCode == 0)
{
    process.Close();
    process.Dispose();
    if (File.Exists(path+filename) && !IsFileLocked(fileInfo) && Directory.Exists(cleanPath))
        File.Move(path, cleanPath);
}
```

I doubt if the scan process is still quarantining the file while you are trying to move.

reference: [know how to check a file is locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use)

And ofcourse, you should handle the else conditions appropriately...

Answer (score 0):

Two tricks that seem to be needed when working with MpCmdRun:

1. Include `-DisableRemediation` to your list of parameters when you call `MpCmdRun`. This causes the process to run very quickly and report the results back via `StandardOutput`.
2. Ignore the returned exit code. Instead, look in the returned StandardOutput string for `"found no threats"` to know if the file is clean. If that is not there, look for a line that starts with `"Threat"` and read it to see what virus was found.